# {"UserId not found."} when using manager.CreateIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

We've been running for ~4 months, and so far we haven't had any complaints. Today, we have somebody complain as creating an account isn't working for them. So I tried myself, and debugging I have indeed found an issue.

We're getting an error of

> {"UserId not found."}

Which happens at this line

> var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

I can not understand why when I try to create an account it works perfectly, but using their email / name it always spits out errors... makes no sense to my inexperienced brain?

Here is my full code

```
public bool CreateUser(string userName, string Email, string Password, string fName, string lName, string country, string ip)
{
    try
    {
        // Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();

        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 1,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false
        };

        var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = userName, Email = Email, EmailConfirmed = false };

        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password);
        
        Utilities u = new Utilities();
        var usersID = user.Id;

        //u.SendMailConfirmation(Email, usersID, fName);

        userDetails(usersID, ip, fName, lName, country);

        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the connection string. If you query the db directly, can you find the user?

Comment: Checked, there is absolutely no trace of the user being created. On local SQL, or live SQL.

Answer (score 0):

And you are sure an user does not already exist with the same email?

Comment: I did a test on my local with a different database to live, so I'm pretty sure it's not that.

Comment: can you check different options like:
customerName / Fakemail,
fakeName / customerMail and
customerName/ customeremail@FakeDomain. Hopefully this will narrow things down.